# Why when passing object inside the directive tag I get string

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-material

I don't have access to the object which I'm passing it inside my directive.

```
// inside dialogController
showAlert(ev) {
    this.mdDialog.show({
            template:"<loader my-master="+this.masterCtrl+"></loader>"
  });

// when debugging, I saw this.masterCtrl is exist as Object 


//inside loader Controller:

export function loader() {
  'ngInject';
  let directive = {
    templateUrl: "app/components/excelLoader/loader.html",
    controller: loaderController,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    scope: {
      words: '=',
      master:'=myMaster'
    },
    replace: true,
    bindToController: true,
    link: linkFunc
  };


   function linkFunc(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
    let vm = scope.vm;
    ctrl.master=attr.myMaster;
  }
  return directive;
}
class loaderController {
  constructor() {
    'ngInject';
    console.log(this.master); //prints string "this.masterCtrl" instead of the Object! 
 }
}
```

What is the correct way to pass this.masterCtrl from dialogController into loader directive and how to use access it in the loader directive?

Comment: Change `"+this.masterCtrl+"` to `"this.masterCtrl"`.

Comment: @camden_kid it still not works, it pass "this.masterCtrl" as string . I'm taking it from attr.myMaster, is there other place to take?

Comment: try to getting from the scope as scope.master

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want? - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/jAovkj?editors=1010#0)

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as vm" ng-cloak="" ng-app="app">
  <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="vm.openDialog($event)">
    Dialog
  </md-button>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('app',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])

.controller('MyController', function($scope, $mdDialog) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.testObject = {test: "blah"};

  vm.openDialog = function(ev) {
    $mdDialog.show({
      controller: 'DialogController',
      controllerAs: 'DialogCtrl',
      template: '<loader my-master="vm.testObject"></loader>',
      parent: angular.element(document.body),
      scope: $scope,
      preserveScope: true,
      targetEvent: ev,
      clickOutsideToClose:true
    });
  };
})

.controller('DialogController', function($scope, $mdDialog) {
})

.directive("loader", loader);

function loader() {
  return {
    template: "<div>Loader directive - {{vm.master.test}}</div>",
    controller: loaderController,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    scope: {
      words: '=',
      master:'=myMaster'
    },
    replace: true,
    bindToController: true,
  };

  function loaderController ($scope) {
    console.log($scope.vm.master);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your link function, assign  `ctrl.master = scope.master;` `attr.myMaster` will read the attribute value from the html tag and will be a string. `scope.master` will be evaluated by angular.

Comment: scope.master is also undefined there :(

Comment: Can you put a console.log(scope) in the link function and see the console output to check what data the scope contains?

Comment: $$childHead
null
$$childTail
null
$$destroyed
false
$$isolateBindings
:
Object
$$listenerCount
:
Object
$$listeners
:
Object
$$nextSibling
:
null
$$phase
:
null
$$prevSibling
:
null
$$watchers
:
Array[7]
$$watchersCount
:
7
$id
:
345
$parent
:
Scope
$root
:
Scope
vm
:
loaderController
__proto__:
Object

Comment: The value must be bound to controller already. Can you delete the line ctrl.master = scope.master in the link function and see the output?

Comment: Nothing relevant there

Comment: Which version of AngularJs are you using? The below link contains details on the various directive binding approaches depending on version. http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/02/exploring-angular-1.3-bindToController.html

Comment: I'm using Angular 1.5.7